# In the Standard Model Lagrangian, why does every term's mass dimension have to be less than four?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, renormalization

In the Standard Model Lagrangian, why does every term's mass dimension have to be less than four? I know that the Lagrangian has to be renormalizable, I guess my question then translates into why aren't higher order terms renormalizable?

Comment: This is quite nicely explained in chapter 12 of Peskin & Schroeder. The short version is that operators of dimension larger than four blow up under the renormalization group when going to the UV.

Comment: The argument responsible is known as *power counting*.